# Indices boost in elasticsearch java api

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot figure out how to boost indices (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-index-boost.html) when using the elasticsearch java api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be set on the SearchSourceBuilder

```
SearchSourceBuilder().query(query).indexBoost(...)
```